# How would I access values as they're updated from a webpage using HTML?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on the code below as a 100 days of code assignment. The assignment requires that I create an automated clicker bot. My question is, the prices of the store items change (increase). How would I use Selenium and Python to access values that change from a webpage? I've attached the code I'm working on below as a screenshot. Also, how would I access and click different store items from the store list? [image]

Comment: the element will become stale if it is updated.  See Stale Element exception:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/StaleElementReference  The exception will be thrown when a method of the WebElement reference is called and the element has gone stale.  As for clicking different items, it looks like you already have a good grasp on locating elements and clicking on them.  You should, however, use webdriverwaits with expected conditions for any site that updates the DOM via Javascript.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML and properly format it instead.

Comment: Your should explain if and how your code fails to do what it expected to do.